# With R, rvest, html_session() %>% html_form() not finding form - need to click Login Button first

Tags: r, session, web-scraping, rvest

We are trying to find an `rvest` solution for this before turning to Selenium or some other approach. We are trying to scrape from the Action Network website - https://www.actionnetwork.com/mlb/public-betting, and need to get logged in first. We have the following:

```
page_url <- "https://www.actionnetwork.com"
page_session <- html_session(page_url)
page_form <- page_session %>% html_form()
filled_form <- page_form %>% set_values(email="*****", password="*****")
page_session %>% submit_form(filled_form)
```

And page form is an empty list currently when this is run, which is the problem. I think this is occurring because the login form does not appear by default on this page. A user needs to first click on **Log In** for the form to show. Is there any way to get this form so we can then `set_values()` and `submit_form()`?

Comment: If you look at the page source for that file, there is no <form> element. Note the page source is not the same as what you see in the "elements" tab of your developer tools. Make sure you look at the actual "source" tab. The form is likely added by javascript and rvest cannot run javascript for you.

Comment: That's what I was worried about. Thank you.

Comment: it is generated by this file: https://static-web-prod.sprtactn.co/_next/static/chunks/2225.ac683d54c6bae30b9eb3.js